# What happens if you move into a territory of your own that has a power token on it? What about territory with someone else's?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Do you get to retrieve the power token?

Answer (score 4):

When you move into a territory that contains your own power token, you simply leave the power token there. That way, when you again exit the territory, it already has your power token.

When you move into a territory that contains a power token of someone else, that power token gets discarded.